# Create a RDD : too many fields => use case class for RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataset of intrusion which is labeled that I want to use to test different supervised machine learning techniques.

So here is a part of my code :

```
object parser_dataset {

   val conf = new SparkConf()
       .setMaster("local[2]")
       .setAppName("kdd")
       .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
        conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(
        classOf[Array[Any]],
        classOf[Array[scala.Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]]],
        classOf[String],
        classOf[Any]
    ))
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)

    def load(file: String): RDD[(Int, String, String,String,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double, Int, Int,Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, String)] = {

        val data = context.textFile(file)

        val res = data.map(x => {

            val s = x.split(",")
        (s(0).toInt, s(1), s(2), s(3), s(4).toInt, s(5).toInt, s(6).toInt, s(7).toInt, s(8).toInt, s(9).toInt, s(10).toInt, s(11).toInt, s(12).toInt, s(13).toInt, s(14).toInt, s(15).toInt, s(16).toInt, s(17).toInt, s(18).toInt, s(19).toInt, s(20).toInt, s(21).toInt, s(22).toInt, s(23).toInt, s(24).toDouble, s(25).toDouble, s(26).toDouble, s(27).toDouble, s(28).toDouble, s(29).toDouble, s(30).toDouble, s(31).toInt, s(32).toInt, s(33).toDouble, s(34).toDouble, s(35).toDouble, s(36).toDouble, s(37).toDouble, s(38).toDouble, s(39).toDouble, s(40).toDouble, s(41))    
        })
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    return res
    }


   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val data = this.load("/home/hvfd8529/Datasets/KDDCup99/kddcup.data_10_percent_corrected")

     data1.collect.foreach(println)
     data.distinct() 

    }
```

}

This is not my code, it was given to me and I just modified some parts (especially the RDD and splitting parts) and **I'm a newbie at Scala and Spark** :)

EDIT:
So I added case class above my load function, like this :

```
case class BasicFeatures(duration:Int, protocol_type:String, service:String, flag:String, src_bytes:Int, dst_bytes:Int, land:Int, wrong_fragment:Int, urgent:Int) 

case class ContentFeatures(hot:Int, num_failed_logins:Int, logged_in:Int, num_compromised:Int, root_shell:Int, su_attempted:Int, num_root:Int, num_file_creations:Int, num_shells:Int, num_access_files:Int, num_outbound_cmds:Int, is_host_login:Int, is_guest_login:Int)

case class TrafficFeatures(count:Int, srv_count:Int, serror_rate:Double, srv_error_rate:Double, rerror_rate:Double, srv_rerror_rate:Double, same_srv_rate:Double, diff_srv_rate:Double, srv_diff_host_rate:Double, dst_host_count:Int, dst_host_srv_count:Int, dst_host_same_srv_rate:Double, dst_host_diff_srv_rate:Double, dst_host_same_src_port_rate:Double, dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate:Double, dst_host_serror_rate:Double, dst_host_srv_serror_rate:Double, dst_host_rerror_rate:Double, dst_host_srv_rerror_rate:Double, attack_type:String )
```

But now I am confused, how can I use these to solve my problem, because I still need a RDD in order to have one feature = one field 
Here is my one line of my file I want to parse :

```
0,tcp,ftp_data,SF,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,150,25,0.17,0.03,0.17,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.05,0.00,normal,20
```

Comment: To be honest, using 22-fields tuples is very bad practise in my opinion, tuple describes nothing. Despite this question, consider using own classes, which has some meanings. You will say "thanks" when you will have to modify your code a year later     ;)

Comment: I concur with @T.Gawęda. Also you'd want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258417/how-to-get-around-the-scala-case-class-limit-of-22-fields) !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get around the Scala case class limit of 22 fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258417/how-to-get-around-the-scala-case-class-limit-of-22-fields)

Comment: Thank you, indeed it is a duplicate, I did suppose i was because it had too many fields but couldn't finda topic about it :/ 
So how would you do it @T.Gawęda to write something "similar" I can use in spark ?

Comment: @LaureD You can create case class. It also will be big, but fields will have some meaning - later you will know which fields means what without reading full code

Comment: @T.Gawęda I modified the code in order to add case class but I don't know how to deal with it afterwards :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max tuple size supported by Scala is 22.Scala function have limit of 22 Parameter. Hence you can not create tuple of size more that 22.