# Is JSON formatting not enough for parsing case class having > 22 fields?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

My case class has 30 fields. For simplicity, I use 4 fields,

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String, age: Int, sex: Sex)

val personFormat1: OFormat[(Long, String)] = ((__ \ "id").format[Long] ~ (__ \ "name").format[String]).tupled
val personFormat2: OFormat[(Int, Sex)] = ((__ \ "age").format[Int] ~ (__ \ "sex").format[Sex]).tupled
implicit val personFormat: Format[Person] = (personFormat1 ~ personFormat2)({
  case ((id, name), (age, sex)) => new Person(id, name, age, sex)
}, (person: Format) => ((person.id, person.name), (person.age, person.sex)))
```

But even after writing formatter with format1 as a group of 22 fields and format2 as a group of 8 fields, I get error when am trying to parse the json of this case class.

Error is 
No Json serializer as JsObject found for type Person. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.

How to write implicit Owrites or OFormat? or how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this using google, and this worked greatly for me

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.julienrf" % "play-json-derived-codecs_2.11" % "3.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use **Play-Json extensions** library for working with JSON with more than 22 fields: https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions

```
libraryDependencies += "ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.8.0"
```

Comment: Thank you. But I tried with this. There is no writes / reads method to de- /serialize in play-json-extensions. How to achieve that? It will be very helpful, if you can point me to that.

Comment: You can use only default format with it, well, you can do some transformation with one field, like do uppercase or so with the `SingletonEncoder` but no more.

Comment: "dīvide et īmpera" would be the best strategy here I suppose. I start to use `play-json-extensions` when started to work with play, but last time I used it a long time ago, I did not meet a task when It's not able to divide JSON into the lesser parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to an implicit writer to do this. Something like this

```
implicit val person= Json.format[Person]
```

Also, if you are using custom data types, like for your case **Sex** you need to specify a reader and writer. You do not need to do this for primitive types like Int, Long, String Etc.

```
  def enumReads[T <: Enum[T]](mkEnum: String => T) = new Reads[T] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[T] =
      json match {
        case JsString(s) => try {
          JsSuccess(mkEnum(s))
        }
        catch {
          case e: IllegalArgumentException =>
            JsError("Not a valid enum value: " + s)
        }
        case v => JsError("Can't convert to enum: " + v)
      }
  }

  implicit val enumWrites = new Writes[Enum[_]] {
    def writes(e: Enum[_]) = JsString(e.toString)
  }

  implicit val sex = enumReads(Sex.valueOf)
```

Also, upgrade to scala 2.11 or later to avoid the limitation of 22 fields in case class. For more info see here: [How to get around the Scala case class limit of 22 fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258417/how-to-get-around-the-scala-case-class-limit-of-22-fields)

Comment: I think, you misunderstood my question. my case class is having 30 fields, more than 22 fields. So, I wrote a custom formatter, which you can see in the example in question. So, even after this custom formatter, I get an error for no json serializer.