# Encoders.product[of a scala trait ].schema in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, database-schema

How to create a schema for spark from a trait?
Considering a trait:

```
trait A{
val name:String
val size:String
}
```

As :

```
Encoders.product[A].schema
```

gives:

```
Error:type arguments do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
```

Also the number of fields will be more then the limit of case class parameters > 200

Comment: Make A extend Product.

Comment: Also you can nest case classes into your case class if number of fields is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case class do supports more than 22 columns, try creating outside all other class/object. If your need is to create a dataframe schema with large number of  fields, this should work.

```
val schema: StructType = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField(name = "name", StringType),
      StructField(name = "size", StringType)
    )
 )
val data = Seq(Row("Ramanan","29"))
spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),schema).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you all the details why this is not working but I am proposing a slightly alternative solution that we frequently use in our Scala Spark projects.

The signature of `Encoders.product` looks like

```
product[T <: scala.Product](implicit evidence$5 : scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])
```

which means tt expects a class that extends `Product` trait and an implicit TypeTag.

Instead of a trait, you could create a `case class` as case classes are extending `Product`(and `Serializable`) automatically.

In order to get a schema you could do:

```scala
case class A (
  val name: String,
  val size: String
)

def createSchema[T <: Product]()(implicit tag: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]) = Encoders.product[T].schema
val schema = createSchema[A]()
schema.printTreeString()

/*
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- size: string (nullable = true)
*/
```

As said in the beginning, I can't explain all the details, just provide a working solution and hoping it fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @mike, but as case class has some limit in the number of parameters, is there a way to get the schema for large number of fields

Comment: We are using case classes with around 200 fields. Not sure if that is the optimal solution, but the limit of 22 fields is only in Scala 2.10.x and not with 2.11 anymore. We just had to adjust the JVM parameter when compiling with Maven: `jvmArg>-Xss2048K</jvmArg>`

Comment: yes @mike, but actually the number of fields were more then 200

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just make sure your trait inherits Product and Serializable, same as case class is by default

```
abstract class MoneV2Base (val x: String) extends Product with Serializable
```