# Scala Slick 3.1.0 StackOverflow error after code generation

Tags: scala, slick, slick-codegen

I've started using the Slick framework and the Code Generator that it's recommended to use.
My problem is that after I generate the code for a table with more than 22 columns (I know about the limits, but the Code Generator let me get over it easily), I just can't compile the project anymore. I'm getting this error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have searched through the whole internet and didn't come up with a solution to this error, in the actual version of Slick 3.1.0.

Comment: This looks like an error in the compiler and involving IDEA. try to compile in the terminal with sbt.

Comment: Tried it, didn't worked too :(

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with a Scala limit of 22 'things' in a Tuple. There's more information on it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152223/why-are-scala-functions-limited-to-22-parameters) on why this is the case.

22 columns in a database table is rather a lot though, so I would suggest if it was possible to split that up into multiple joined tables that would be a way around the issue.

Or indeed wait until Typesafe fix the issue in a future version of Scala. If indeed that ever happens.

Comment: But in their [tutorial](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/code-generation.html) they *support* more than 22 values in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

the slick / shapeless "slickless" library allows you to use slick and get past the hard 22 column (case class-induced) restriction:

https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/08/08/slickless.html