# Summing "Large" Nat's

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given:

```
scala> import shapeless.nat.
_0   _10   _12   _14   _16   _18   _2    _21   _3   _5   _7   _9      natOps            
_1   _11   _13   _15   _17   _19   _20   _22   _4   _6   _8   apply   toInt             

scala> import shapeless.ops.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat._
```

After > 3 minutes, the following code has not compiled/run. Why's that?

```
scala> Sum[_22, _22]
```

Also, looking at the above REPL auto-completion, does `_44` even exist in shapeless?

Comment: Looks suspiciously similar to [max size of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4152223/1240268) but can't see where they're defined in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why is it so slow?

Let's start with a smaller number. When you ask for `Sum[_4, _4]`, the compiler is going to go looking for an instance, and it'll find [these two methods](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.3.2/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/nat.scala#L48):

```
implicit def sum1[B <: Nat]: Aux[_0, B, B] = new Sum[_0, B] { type Out = B }
implicit def sum2[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit
  sum: Sum[A, Succ[B]]
): Aux[Succ[A], B, sum.Out] = new Sum[Succ[A], B] { type Out = sum.Out }
```

The first one is clearly out since `_4` is not `_0`. It knows that `_4` is the same as `Succ[_3]` (more on that in a second), so it'll try `sum2` with `A` as `_3` and `B` as `_4`.

This means we need to find a `Sum[_3, _5]` instance. `sum1` is out for similar reasons as before, so we try `sum2` again, this time with `A = _2` and `B = _5`, which means we need a `Sum[_2, _6]`, which gets us back to `sum2`, with `A = _1` and `B = _6`, which sends us looking for a `Sum[_1, _7]`. This is the last time we'll use `sum2`, with `A = _0` and `B = _7`. This time when we go looking for a `Sum[_0, _8]` we'll hit `sum1` and we're done.

So it's clear that for `n + n` we're going to have to do `n + 1` implicit searches, and during each one the compiler is going to be doing type equality checks and other stuff (update: see Miles's answer for an explanation of what the biggest problem here is) that requires traversing the structure of the `Nat` types, so we're in exponential land. The compiler really, really isn't designed to work efficiently with types like this, which means that even for small numbers, this operation is going to take a long time.

### Side note 1: implementation in Shapeless

Off the top of my head I'm not entirely sure why `sum2` isn't defined like this:

```
implicit def sum2[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit
  sum: Sum[A, B]
): Aux[Succ[A], B, Succ[sum.Out]] = new Sum[Succ[A], B] { type Out = Succ[sum.Out] }
```

This is much faster, at least on my machine, where `Sum[_18, _18]` compiles in four seconds as opposed to seven minutes and counting.

### Side note 2: induction heuristics

This doesn't seem to be a case where Typelevel Scala's [`-Yinduction-heuristics`](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/2.12.1.md) helps—I just tried compiling Shapeless with the `@inductive` annotation on `Sum` and it's still seems pretty much exactly as horribly slow as without it.

### What about 44?

The `_1`, `_2`, `_3` type aliases are defined in code produced by [this boilerplate generator](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.3.2/project/Boilerplate.scala#L369) in Shapeless, which is configured only to produce values up to 22. In this case specifically, this is an entirely arbitrary limit. We can write the following, for example:

```
type _23 = Succ[_22]
```

And we've done exactly the same thing the code generator does, but going one step further.

It doesn't really matter much that Shapeless's `_N` aliases stop at 22, though, since they're just aliases. The important thing about a `Nat` is its structure, and that's independent of any nice names we might have for it. Even if Shapeless didn't provide any `_N` aliases at all, we could still write code like this:

```
import shapeless.Succ, shapeless.nat._0, shapeless.ops.nat.Sum

Sum[Succ[Succ[_0]], Succ[Succ[_0]]]
```

And it would be exactly the same as writing `Sum[_2, _2]`, except that it's a lot more annoying to type.

So when you write `Sum[_22, _22]` the compiler isn't going to have any trouble representing the result type (i.e. 44 `Succ`s around a `_0`), even though it doesn't have a `_44` type alias.

Comment: Re: Side Note 1, is it worthwhile to make a PR against shapeless for re-defining `sum2`?

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Travis's excellent answer, it appears that it's the use of the member type in the definition of `sum2` which is the root of the problem. With the following definition of `Sum` and its instances,

```
trait Sum[A <: Nat, B <: Nat] extends Serializable { type Out <: Nat }

object Sum {
  def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum[A, B]): Aux[A, B, sum.Out] = sum

  type Aux[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat] = Sum[A, B] { type Out = C }

  implicit def sum1[B <: Nat]: Aux[_0, B, B] = new Sum[_0, B] { type Out = B }
  implicit def sum2[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat]
    (implicit sum : Sum.Aux[A, Succ[B], C]): Aux[Succ[A], B, C] =
      new Sum[Succ[A], B] { type Out = C }
}
```

which replaces the use of the member type with an additional type variable, the compile time is 0+noise on my machine both with and without `-Yinduction-heurisitics`.

I think that the issue we're seeing is a pathological case for subtyping with member types.

Aside from that, the induction is so small that I wouldn't actually expect `-Yinduction-heurisitics` to make much of an improvement.

**Update** now [fixed in shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/commit/e3c24c37cde1e0a8559d7b51f6270393fbd29751).