# Java - Create Scala function with an arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: java, scala, function, closures, interop

Let's say I have a Scala singleton object called `HelloWorld` with the following method:

```
def abacaba(m: (String) => Unit): Unit = {

}
```

When I try to call `HelloWorld.abacaba` from a Java class, my IDE (Intellij) tells me that it wants an object of type `Function1<String, BoxedUnit>`. This shouldn't be too hard; I can just implement the abstract methods and pass the anonymous class to scala.

Now, let's say I change `abacaba` to require a function accepting two strings:

```
def abacaba(m: (String, String) => Unit): Unit = {

}
```

Again, this isn't a problem; I just need to give Scala a `Function2<String, String, BoxedUnit>`. However, this doesn't work when I require that the function accept a very large number of arguments (from testing, I know that this must be more than 22):

```
def abacaba(m: (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,String, String,String, String,String, String,String, String, String, String, String) => Unit): Unit = {

}
```

Now, from Java it simply requests an `Object`. In this case (although I'm obviously never going to have to deal with this many parameters in the real world) **how would I create an appropriate Scala function from my Java class?** I'd prefer not to have to write utility methods in Scala or use Reflection.

Comment: You can use javap to deassemble the generated class file of your `HelloWorld` and see how scala compiler invoked the function `m`.

Comment: @glee8e oh now this is weird! The *Scala* compiler actually throws a compile-time error when I try to require more than 22 parameters: `error: type Function23 is not a member of package scala` Looks like Scala simply doesn't support functions with more than 22 parameters...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152223/why-are-scala-functions-limited-to-22-parameters

Comment: @danielnixon Thanks, didn't see that!

Comment: Then what did you do with the code in your question for Java to require an `Object`?

Comment: @Jasper-M I added more than 22 parameters.