# What is the maximum size of Tuple, Array and List is supported in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Scala language, of what maximum size that a developer can define for

- Tuple
- Array
- List

Thanks

Comment: You should at least take some effort to specify precisely what you mean by *"define length"*. What exactly do you mean by "length"? The `Int` value returned by the `.size` method on `Array` and `List`? That would be different than the `Long` length that you theoretically could obtain on a computer with a stupidly gigantic amount of memory that can hold more than 2^31-1 list elements.

Comment: @Andrey, Here is an example of what I meant, like array[10]. Meaning the array is of size 10. Having established what I meant above, I have updated the title and body with size. Hope this have eradicated the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuple: 22 (see [Why are scala functions limited to 22 parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152223/why-are-scala-functions-limited-to-22-parameters))

List: Practically speaking, since various list length methods return `Int`, it's effectively `Int.MaxValue`

Array: Same as List, but as Andrey points out in the comments, you cannot ask for more than `Int` entries

Comment: Arrays are also limited by the simple fact that you cannot ask for more than `Int` entries anyway... It's more 32-bit backwards-compatibility issue rather than memory issue.